# How to quote formula result?

Tags: google-sheets, url, importxml

I have a function which returns a URL from hyperlink as a first parameter to IMPORTXML function.

For the function to work I need to put the output of that function in quotes, how do I do it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As pnuts said, you don't need quote marks there. Think of them as a container we have to use to separate our text from formulas, as in `= "not" & B3`, so that the string is recognized as such. If the text comes from a formula, it is already known to be text.

---

That said, if you actually had to put quotes around formula output, that would be done with

```
"""" & linkURL(A2) & """"
```

The rule is that quote marks `"` inside a string must be doubled. So, `""""` is a string with a single character `"`, and `="""" & A2 & """"` outputs `"url"` if the cell A2 contains url.